Delphi: double indexing a pointer-of-array leads to “Array type required” error
A pointer of arrays is indexed once to get the array, then indexed again to get the element. This C-style trick should work with {$POINTERMATH ON}, but it definitely doesn't:
{$POINTERMATH ON}
...
type
  TYMMQWords = Array[0 .. 3] of UInt64;
  PYMMQWords = ^TYMMQWords; 

var 
  currentFlag: Integer; 
  temp: UInt64; 
  arrayFlags: PYMMQWords;

begin
  temp := arrayFlags[currentFlag][0];
end;

Let's take it step by step:

arrayFlags[currentFlag] is obviously a 4-element array of QWords. That's how pointer arithmetic works, and moreover, there is even no ambiguity here, this expression would simply give an error without {$POINTERMATH ON}.
In turn, arrayFlags[currentFlag][0], that is, (arrayFlags[currentFlag])[0], being an element of a QWord array, should denote a QWord element. No ambiguity, as well.

However, Delphi gives a compiler error here:

Array type required

Where am I wrong?

@500 - Internal Server Error, if temp := arrayFlags[currentFlag]; is valid, temp should denote an array per definitionem, hence it can be indexed as well.

But temp is not an array - it's just an UInt64.

Sorry for misunderstanding. temp := arrayFlags[currentFlag]; is already not valid, as arrayFlags is a pointer of arrays, hence arrayFlags[currentFlag] is an array (of 4 elements).

Delphi/Pascal is able to dereference pointers for you automatically under conditions. But when both ways (implying a dereference vs. writing dereferencing code instructions) are possible the compiler won't magically know which of both is correct for your intentions. Hence, use ^ for precision.

So you say the arrayFlags[currentFlag][0] is not ambigous? Why?

I say it is ambiguous. Wanting arrayFlags[Integer][Integer] needs Array[] of Array[], while arrayFlags[Integer]^[Integer] needs Array[] of ^Array[] etc.

Possible duplicate of 4 years ago's Accessing 2-dimensional array via pointer using pointer math: Array type required with the same compiler error and still insisting on wanting a different syntax.

This looks like a compiler bug. The compiler is simply not interpreting this code correctly when POINTERMATH is used with a pointer to an array.
Here is another example that shows the problem is even worse:
{$POINTERMATH ON}
...
type
  TYMMQWords = Array[0 .. 3] of UInt64;
  PYMMQWords = ^TYMMQWords; 

var 
  arr: array[0..3] of TYMMQWords; 
  currentFlag: Integer; 
  temp: TYMMQWords; 
  arrayFlags: PYMMQWords;

begin
  arrayFlags := @arr[0];
  currentFlag := 3;
  temp := arrayFlags[currentFlag];   // ERROR
  temp := (arrayFlags+currentFlag)^; // OK
end;

The compiler error is completely wrong:

E2010 Incompatible types: 'TYMMQWords' and 'UInt64'

Neither temp nor arrayFlags[currentFlag] are a UInt64. arrayFlags is a pointer to a TYMMQWords, and so logically arrayFlags[currentFlag] should yield (a reference to) a TYMMQWords instance. But the compiler seems to think that indexing this pointer yields an element of the array rather than the array itself.
So, the Array type required error makes more sense when taken in this context.  In arrayFlags[currentFlag][0], the compiler is clearly trying to apply the [0] to a UInt64, not to a TYMMQWords, hence the Array type required error.
I have opened a bug ticket with Embarcadero:
RSS-2077: PointerMath is broken for array types

Thanks! Obviously the workaround proposed by @AmigoJack (arrayFlags + currentFlag)^[0] has no problem aside that it's not elegant. So the problem itself is solved now, but it's not acceptable that Delphi has such compiler issues, thanks for the answer!

@ZoltánBíró Yes, that is the syntax you will have to use until the compiler is fixed.

PYMMQWords is a Pointer, not an Array.

arrayFlags[currentFlag] does not access an array, hence you cannot use indices here.
You have to dereference (^) your pointer, e.g. arrayFlags^ to come from PYMMQWords back to TYMMQWords - then you can also use indices via arrayFlags^[currentFlag].


Edit: so OP wanted this:

var 
  arrayFlags: PYMMQWords;  // Not just one TYMMQWords but many in a series.
  currentFlag: Integer;  // Indicating which of those TYMMQWords he wants to access.



For accessing the 1st TYMMQWords one would need to write arrayFlags^ to then access the 4 elements of that array.
For accessing the 3rd TYMMQWords one would need to write (arrayFlags+ 2)^ to wander 2 times the size of TYMMQWords with the pointer to then be able to access another instance of an array with 4 elements.

In sum the overall code for access should be:
UInt64value:= (arrayFlags+ currentFlag)^[index0..3];

...with currentFlag starting with 0 and being incremented as wanted.

Don't understand what you say, I use {$POINTERMATH ON} just for having the c-style behaviour where you can use a pointer right as an array.

You most likely want (arrayFlags+ 0)^[3] for the 4th element of the 1st array in your pointer. Pointer arithmetics in Delphi is primarily/only about increments, not indices.

Negative. Imagine an array having unlimited (or at least undefined) number of elements. Say, currentFlag is 3, so I need the 4th element. As this 4th element is also an array, I need the first (index 0) element from this 4th array.

That would be (arrayFlags+ 3)^[0] - you could have chosen better variable names and explain your overall intentions with it.

Now it correct, but still doesn't explain why my original version wouldn't be OK.

Because you misunderstood pointer math in the context of Delphi and imply everything from C can be done here. Now un-downvote, since votings are for judging overall quality and not expressing frustration when things just aren't how one imagined it.

@AmigoJack don't tell people how to vote. That's up to us. The real issue here is that you don't understand what POINTERMATH ON means.

@DavidHeffernan If I don't understand then why am I aware of (arrayFlags+ 3)?

The docs for PointerMath states: It also allows you to treat such a pointer variable as an unbounded array using the array [] operator. Notice in the example above that incrementing the index of an array of a type is equivalent to incrementing a pointer to that type. An increment of one bumps the pointer by the size an array element in bytes, not by one byte.

@UweRaabe Both you guys are no help here - I read the docs (and would have linked to it and formatted a quotation), yet I'm convinced this is only possible for non-array pointers, as otherwise the syntax is ambiguous. Why does none of you both come up with a different answer? It's even undefined which Delphi version is used here (versus the docs).

@AmigoJack, I removed my downvote, but just because I currently use exactly your workaround as (arrayFlags + currentFlag)^[0], thanks for it! But your answer is still not correct, Delphi should interpret the original version correctly.

"as otherwise the syntax is ambiguous". It's not ambiguous. The first [] indexes into the array of fixed arrays. The second [] indexes into the specified fixed array.
